# How does an HTTP request get split up into multiple packets?

Tags: http, tcp, packet

I'm an application developer, looking into trying to understand how HTTP request/responses are passed at the transport layer, and found some good resources that have been helping me, but there are still some questions I can't track down

- [How is HTTP converted to TCP?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6007/42100)

This thread helped me understand that as a request is passed down each layer, the layer is "encapsulating" the payload with headers until it's sent over the wire

[image]

So my current understanding is that the HTTP Request is really a payload, which then the TCP layer will throw some headers on. These headers seem to mostly be used to track the order of the packets of the messages that will be going back-and-forth

**TCP Headers:**
[image]

And then IP headers are slapped on (https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/ip-protocol-header/)
Which just track the source/destination and size of the packet

---

It's clear that a every HTTP request does not map 1:1 to a packet, based on what I have found it looks like the requests can be broken up into pieces to be streamed over TCP

If the request needs to be broken up, where is the code that does that?

Comment: No. You have it back to front, or rather inside-out. All the HTTP is in the TCP payload; all the TCP is in the IP payload; and all the IP is in the Ethernet payload. It is IP headers wrapping the TCP headers wrapping the HTTP headers wrapping, or rather preceding, the HTTP request body. It's right there in your picture, where HTTP is the upper layer.

Comment: TCP segmentation happens in the TCP layer; IP packetization is done in the IP layer; and fragmentation is done by routers.